# Netbeans - hibernate reverse engineering tutorial, POJO creation fails

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to teach my self hibernate with a net-beans tutorial. Here are one link, but I tried several, using same sample database:  (so far I am only allowed one hyperlink ;0 )

- http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

I would have thought Netbeans makes it simple, but the creation of pojos / mapping files always fails! I do create cfg.xml + reveng.xml, but when trying to create mapping files, i can choose my tables in the wizard, add them, but after clicking finish the IDE does not create anything !! (plus: I am not able to click next, only finish ! / as some tutorial asks u to click next)

Now I really wonder what could be the cause, I would appreciate any help. I checked NetBeans mailing / bug list - there solutions did not work for me.

I am using NB 6.9.1 - (currently downloading newest hibernate libraries / zip file, but not even sure what to do with them when done)

Thanks for any help / advice - I had found one question on stackoverflow, but there was no real solution given !!

Best Regards
Alexis

Comment: OK ===>> this seems to be a dodgy issue here !! I did this over an over, and now for the first time it created the files required. BUT: How come it does not work with Tomcat server !?!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG =>  ok, simply, because I did not close the opened files like xml and helper files, NB would not create the mapping files - need to close the files !! And for anyone coming accross same issue, also make sure this line is correct

org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory

Cos as described in tutorial, this line actually is not available in NB - needs to be added manually !! -> figured that out yesterday, however all in all, i just found it to be a dodgy matter. !!

Comment: ===>>> however, i can not use NB HQL editor !! it throws error of cant connect - but if i use the sql command vie NB services window, I can retriev information from the DB  -  NB and hibernate are not verywell set up are they ?/ what could be the cause ? am I missing libraries ? some settings ??